# Need help taking a line from a text file and sorting that line into multiple variables

Tags: c++, hex, rgb

I`m trying to take a name and 3 numbers from a text file then take that input and store the name into color and the 3 numbers into r,g,b then it will take the r,g,b numbers and turn them into hex color codes.the text file format is as follows

```
color1 190 190 190

color2 20 50 70
```

This following code is where my problem lies

```
ifstream ReadFile; 
ReadFile.open(filename); 

if(ReadFile.fail()) 
{
cout<<"Could not open "<<filename<<endl;
}
else
{
   while ( getline (ReadFile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }


}
//for(string line; getline(ReadFile, line, '.'); ) 
//{
//cout<<line<<endl;

//}
ReadFile.close();


//cout<<"Enter the value of RGB(from range 0 to 255):";
    cin>>r>>g>>b;
    cout<<rgbtohex(r,b,g,true)<<endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! U need to do the string operations

Comment: [Assuming you need help in extracting integers from each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987461/extraction-of-integers-from-strings)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting compile errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read file line by line and tokenize that line with **space** delemeter

```
std::ifstream file("fileName");
std::string   line;

while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream   linestream(line);
    std::string         data;
    std::string         color;
    int                 r;
    int                 g;
    int                 b;

    // If you have truly space delimited data use getline() with third parameter.
    // If your data is just white space separated data
    // then the operator >> will do (it reads a space separated word into a string).
    // so no need to third params
    std::getline(linestream, data);  
    // example of comma delemeter
    //std::getline(linestream, data,','); 
    // Read the integers using the operator >>
    linestream >> r>> g>>b;
    // and before calling close file file you have store all r,g,b value other wise 
    //process within this loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you seems to be having issue parsing the input line to get the color name, `r`, `g`, `b` values as your code for reading from text file is correct. For that, you can use `istringstream` object (`iss`) to get the values for multiple variables of different types separated by spaces from each file line

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string filename = "colors.txt"; // Color input file
  ifstream ReadFile; 
  istringstream iss;
  ReadFile.open(filename); 
  string line, color;
  int r, g, b;

  if(ReadFile.fail()) {
    cout<<"Could not open "<<filename<<endl;
  }
  else {
    while (getline (ReadFile,line)) {
      iss.clear();
      iss.str(line);
      iss >> color >> r >> g >> b;
      cout << "Color: " << color << endl;
      cout << "R: " << r << endl;
      cout << "G: " << g << endl;
      cout << "B: " << b << endl;
    }
    ReadFile.close();
  }
}
```